# deploy front-end applications behind apache

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, devops, rundeck

I have a eCommerce website which has multiple front end application over a same domain, of which 3-4 applications are written in Angular4, 2-3 applications are written in Angular1.2 and few application are pure TypeScript applications. All application are being build by NPM.

I have few questions/doubts:

- Shall I deploy each application individually? (takes lot of time to deploy in each environment).
- Shall I build once or each time while deploying on a environment. (npm install/build might fail on production server ).
- How to release the versions and where to store? (may be git and git tag)
- We have other Java application and are configured in jenkins, which has a release process and easy to maintain. How can we have same kind of pattern for front-end applications.

Comment: Have you ever thought about continues deployment (CD)?

Answer (score 0):

I think deploying all your application at once (in one time) is a wrong decision.

I recommend you to use continues integration (CI) and continues deployment (CD) on Git.

Take GitHub as an example, and you might be noticed that lots of projects are using [travis continuous integration](https://travis-ci.org/). It helps them to run all their tests on each git push (or Pull request), and it will reduce bugs.

GitLab is offering a perfect and free [CI and CD](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/) tools which are easy to use and set up.

There are definitely different ways to use Gitlab CI and CD, but you should define some different stages and jobs to run your app tests, then run a deployment script on your server using SSH, you can use  GitLab variables to define your server password and other information and they are safe there.

And you can have a protected branch (let's say `production` branch) and just you or some other trusted developers can push to it, on each of the push or merge actions that happen to the `production` branch, a `deployment` job which you already defined on GitLab **CI and CD** tools will run and after all tests passed successfully, it will run the deploy script.

Obviously, each of your projects should have their own repository which makes it easier to deploy each of them at different times.